# Data import from new reports and automatically update existing records in existing data

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, dax, powerquery

I seek expert advice of all of you in accomplishing my work related task.

**Task :** Task it to perform Analysis on reports obtained to WorkSafe Monthly and weekly and getting valuable information out.
**For example** :

1. Number of injuries on monthly basis drilled down by department and     divisions.
2. Total days lost in year
3. Count of type of claims
4. Possible return date.

So i receive these reports and i add some modified columns to it. Like **Correct employee names** and their **ID's** just to create a relationship between Employee database in Powerpivot so that i could get their position, dept and division.

Now every month in new report there could be 2 or 3 new claims added to it, and some existing claims with updates info. like Updated **return to work date, Short term disability days** etc.

Currently i go through them manually and it's really time consuming and tiring. if there there was older claims weren't getting updates i could've just imported from a folder using power query and added steps to remove duplicates. However, if i remove duplicate claims using powerquery now, basically i'll be removing same claims with updated info.

Could anyone you here suggest an efficient way to do it with power query or with other approach?

Thanks in Advance. I'd appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use PowerQuery and select your source From File -> From Folder, when you choose to combine and edit you will get a table with its first column named Source.Name; which you could use to differentiate the updates.

For instance: If I start with two excel files in the same folder (theoretically, they could be different date source files for you)...

WS1.xlsx:
[image]

WS1 - Copy.xlsx:[image]

Then I use the folder they are both in as the source...

[image]

(Navigate to your folder as appropriate.)

...and select Combine & Edit...

[image]

...and select the worksheet...

[image]

Then I get this:

[image]

...and it is clear what information came from what source file.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. i had a doubt in mind about existing record with updated info in new report. so i removed duplicates selecting column containing primary key. and it worked existing records did get updated. Thanks for your time and effort!